# How to release the cashed memory on a linux server

Tags: linux

How to release the big chunk of cashed memory on Linux system?

When I use

```
free
```

command, I find that Linux used a lot of memory for cache and others even though I don't have other job running. My targeted job failed due to memory issues.

I found the one solution listed below to clear the cached memory. I want to know some other solutions to release the other memory besides rebooting the machine using

```
sudo reboot
```

Maybe kill all the processes?

Comment: Read http://linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 0):

I later found the following command will serve the purpose.

```
sudo sync && sudo echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Detailed explanations: https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5670/clean-up-memory-on-linux.